# mysqli: Why do I need a 'if' statement to create a Table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am learning MySQL with PHP and how to create tables & insert the Data. But I am particular confused about the following code:

```
//SECTION 1
$sql = "CREATE TABLE ingredients (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
quanity INT(6) NOT NULL,
package INT(6) NOT NULL,
item VARCHAR(50),
cost DECIMAL(18,2),
store VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";

//SECTION 2
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table ingredients created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

//SECTION 3
$conn->close();
```

So I copied and pasted this code and ran it in my browser, then checked localhost/phpmyadmin and sure enough the TABLE was created.

However, I then deleted the code and **ran only SECTION 1**, (section 2 & 3 were deleted and not present in the code) assuming this was all I needed to create a Table. After refreshing my browser, no Table in my Database was created.

So I took another look and thought, its probably because I didn't close the connection. So this time I inserted SECTION 1 & SECTION 3 and left out SECTION 2.

This also did not create a Table to my surprise. So this is where I am confused at. Why do I need SECTION 2? As far as I can tell from reading it, it only prints out a string, which is just a small notification to me or any user that a Table was created, but it doesn't seem vital in the making of a Table. Why then, can I NOT create a Table without it? I am confused!

Comment: Section 1 only creates a PHP string containing your table definition, nothing more than that; it's section 2 that executes that request against the database. Section 2 is what does the actual work based on what section 1 defines should be done

Comment: Specifically `$conn->query($sql)` is what is actually executing your query.

Comment: Section 1 is just instruction, section 2 executes those instructions. It is like a house plan and house getting built, section1 is nothing but a plan, section 2 builds this plan ... if that helps.

Comment: You seriously need to check out the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) which not one other person has mentioned here and absolutely should have. The link is a good starting point, it is to `query`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is **not** that you're missing `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { ... }`. The **problem** is that you're missing `$conn->query($sql)`.

`$conn->query($sql)` is a function that returns `TRUE` if it succeeds. By calling `if` on this function, you are both running it and checking its return value in one line, rather than separating these into two lines.

So, even if you don't want to run an `if` statement, you still need to run `$conn->query($sql)` on its own line.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I specifically chose you because I felt like I got the most understanding from your version of explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain your code:

Here you only assign an SQL query-like string to variable **$sql**.

```
//SECTION 1
$sql = "CREATE TABLE ingredients (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
quanity INT(6) NOT NULL,
package INT(6) NOT NULL,
item VARCHAR(50),
cost DECIMAL(18,2),
store VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";
```

Now you need to execute the SQL script:

```
//SECTION 2
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table ingredients created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}
```

You don't **need** an if statement, you can do only:

```
//SECTION 2
$conn->query($sql);
```

However, the if statements let you check, if the query was actually executed, meaning, if you get *true*, the query was executed and you know, that the table was created, else, you get an error `$conn->error` that you can process and see, what went wrong.

Closing connection, to release DB memory

```
//SECTION 3
$conn->close();
```